# iOS crash in simple block with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, crash, avaudioplayer

My app has some crashes reported via XCode. The source is the following function:

```
class SoundManager
{
  static var players=[AVAudioPlayer]()

  class func stop(id: String)
  {
    for i in (0..<players.count).reverse()
    {
      if players[i].url?.lastPathComponent==id+".m4a"
      {
        players[i].stop()
        players.removeAtIndex(i)
      }
    }
  }
```

Last part of the log can be different:

```
0   (null) in objc_retain ()
1   (null) in static SoundManager.stop(String) -> ()

0   (null) in objc_msgSend ()
1   (null) in static SoundManager.stop(String) -> () ()

0   (null) in objc_class::nameForLogging() ()
1   (null) in cache_t::bad_cache(objc_object*, objc_selector*, objc_class*) ()
2   (null) in cache_t::bad_cache(objc_object*, objc_selector*, objc_class*) ()
3   (null) in objc_msgSend_corrupt_cache_error ()
4   (null) in static SoundManager.stop(String) -> () ()

0   (null) in OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32Barrier ()
1   (null) in realizeClass(objc_class*) ()
2   (null) in lookUpImpOrForward ()
3   (null) in _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 ()
4   (null) in _objc_msgSend_uncached ()
5   (null) in static SoundManager.stop(String) -> () ()

0   (null) in lookUpImpOrForward ()
1   (null) in _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 ()
2   (null) in _objc_msgSend_uncached ()
3   (null) in static SoundManager.stop(String) -> () ()

0   (null) in __exceptionPreprocess ()
1   (null) in objc_exception_throw ()
2   (null) in -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
3   (null) in ___forwarding___ ()
4   (null) in _CF_forwarding_prep_0 ()
5   (null) in static SoundManager.stop(String) -> () ()

0   (null) in -[AVAudioPlayer url] ()
1   (null) in static SoundManager.stop(String) -> ()
```

I was able to get it only once and did not succeed in reproducing. Can you advise?

Comment: Try printing details about the `players` array as the first line of your function.  I'm guessing that the objects in there are in some kind of bad state.

Comment: I get those crashes from end users. I am unable to reproduce it, so printing will be of no help :-(

Comment: I see.  When you said "via Xcode" I thought you meant while you were debugging.